# D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

This is my `build.gradle`:

[image]

Please help me.

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.deshi_diet_assistant"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-date-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-signin')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"

    //Firebase Database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'

    //Firebase auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:{{ android.firebase.auth }}"

    //Facebook login
     implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'

    //FBSDK
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'


    // //google sign in
    // implementation (project(':react-native-google-signin')){
    //     exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    // }

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I'm running into this same issue with my react-native project. From what I can tell so far, I think it may be due to google updating some of their libraries and some library you depend on not pinning the version number. I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Do you by chance have react-native-device-info in your package.json?

Comment: no i dont have react-native-device-info in my package.json

Comment: I finally fixed my issue. I had a library that I wasn't specifying the version number of. Looking at your file it could be.     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'

    //Firebase auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'. I have an iOS background and react-native is my introduction to android so I am not intimately familiar with build versions etc but the firebase stuff at 17 could be using the new androidx libraries but you can't mix those with non androidx libraries. I'm not sure what version you should use but you could try '16.+'

Comment: my firebase database and auth versions are already 17.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0" //Add this
        firebaseVersion = "17.0.0" //Add this
    }
```